# How to train a neural network with a custom loss function that is informed by outputs from the input layer in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

This seems to be a very commonly asked question, but I am still struggling to find a minimal workable example to solidify my understanding. So here goes another attempt with a MWE.

I am trying to build a neural network that goes from `(x1, x2) -> (y1,y2,y3,y4)`. So the input is vector with the shape `(2,)` and the output is also a vector with the shape `(4,)`. The input and output also ought to follow a simple constraint:

```
y1/sin(2*x1) + y2/cos(x1+x2) - y3/sin(x1+x2) - y4/cos(2*x2) = 0
```

This is my implementation for TensorFlow 2 (2.4.0) (a little lengthy, but runs in less than 5 seconds):

```
import tensorflow               as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy                    as np

from tensorflow              import keras
from keras                   import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import time
import os

def create_vec(x1, x2):
    M = np.zeros(4)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.005, 4)
    M[0] = np.sin(2*x1 )+noise[0]
    M[1] = np.cos(x1+x2)+noise[1]
    M[2] = np.sin(x1+x2)+noise[2]
    M[3] = np.cos(2*x2 )+noise[3]

    return M

if __name__=="__main__":
    start = time.time()

    print(f"tensorflow version = {tf.__version__}")

    # generated all the inputs and outputs
    inputs  = []
    outputs = []
    for x1 in np.linspace(0.1, 1, 20):
        for x2 in np.linspace(0.1, 1, 20):
            M = create_vec(x1, x2)
            inputs.append(np.array([x1,x2]))
            outputs.append(M)

    inputs  = np.array(inputs )
    outputs = np.array(outputs)

    # all inputs and outputs have been generated. now, do a split

    train_input, test_input, train_output, test_output = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    tf_inputs  = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_input,  dtype=tf.float32)

    print (f"tf_inputs = {tf_inputs.shape}")

    input_layer  = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
    x            = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu" )(input_layer)
    x            = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu" )(x)
    output_layer = layers.Dense(4, activation="linear")(x)

    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        
        print (f"y_true.shape = {y_true.shape}")
        print (f"type(y_true) = {type(y_true)}")
        mse_loss  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))

        sin_2x1      = tf.sin(tf_inputs[:,0])
        sum_sin_x1x2 = tf.cos(tf_inputs[:,0]+tf_inputs[:,1])
        sum_cos_x1x2 = tf.sin(tf_inputs[:,0]+tf_inputs[:,1])
        cos_2x2      = tf.cos(tf_inputs[:,1])

        trig_loss = y_pred[:,0]/sin_2x1 + y_pred[:,1]/sum_cos_x1x2 - y_pred[:,2]/sum_sin_x1x2 - y_pred[:,3]/cos_2x2
        trig_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(trig_loss))

        return mse_loss + trig_loss

    # setting up the model in totality
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    # compiling the model
    model.compile (optimizer="adam", loss=custom_loss, metrics=[keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])

    # allow it to fit
    history = model.fit (train_input, train_output, epochs=512, validation_split=0.2)
    print(f"MSE loss: {history.history['loss'][-1]}")
    print(f"val loss: {history.history['val_loss'][-1]}")

    results = model.evaluate(test_input, test_output)
    print (results)
    stop = time.time()
    print (f"Time for computation is {stop-start}")
```

This program should fail with a `ValueError`.

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 320 for '{{node custom_loss/truediv}} = RealDiv[T=DT_FLOAT](custom_loss/strided_slice_6, custom_loss/Sin)' with input shapes: [32], [320].
```

I understand the nature of the error, I think. The training likely takes place in batches and even though the train set is 320, one of the batches is of size 32. But I do not know how to resolve this.

Can anyone provide a working solution of this relatively simple (I think) regression problem? My assumption is that with the addition of such a "trigonometric"/custom error, I can develop a more robust neural network. I have been scouring the internet on how to include inputs to create a custom error for a neural network, but they never go beyond the very simple `K.reduce_mean(inputs)` addition to the custom error.